# xargs split string by space

Tags: bash, shell, sh, xargs

I have the following shell script:

```
serial_numbers=$(ddcutil detect | grep "Serial number" | awk '{print $3}' | uniq)
echo $serial_numbers | xargs -P $(echo $serial_numbers | wc -w) -I % ddcutil setvcp 10 100 --sn %
```

The variable `$serial_number` contains the string `'8TRNJQ2 FGVF2Y2'`.
`xargs` interprets this string as one single argument and produces only one invocation of `ddcutil setvcp`. But I want `xargs`to split the string at the space, so iÍ get two invocations with `8TRNJQ2` and `FGVF2Y2` as arguments.

Edit: using `-t ' '` gives me strange results for the last part in the string: `'FGVF2Y2'$'\n'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xargs` works fine if you pipe it directly from a command, but not if you `echo` the result of the same command output.

Add this transformation in your command:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $serial_numbers | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -P $(echo $serial_numbers | wc -w) -I % ddcutil setvcp 10 100 --sn %
```

`xargs` will now understand that you want to split on your serial numbers.

Alternatively, you could put the `tr` in your first line and store the separated serial numbers in the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I was not aware of the `tr` command

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` has `-n` option which is someway usable for splitting one-string input.
But I noticed, that using `-I` together with `-n1` destroys its  splitting behavior (*unquoted blanks do not terminate input items* - `man xargs`).
So another way to break a line besides using `tr` is explicitly passing delimiter to `xargs` with `-d`.
Also you will need to add `-n` to your `echo` to remove trailing newline, that you see as `$'\n'` (and it'll break subsequent piping):

```
echo -n "a b c" | xargs -d " " -I% echo letter_%
```

or you can just insert another xargs in your pipe:

```
echo -n "a b c" | xargs -n1 | xargs -I% echo letter_%
```